# Python3 kernel available when Jupyter notebook is opened from my home directory, but not any other directories

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I am trying to set up a deep learning environment on my Ubuntu machine (16.04). I have installed Anaconda and when I type

```
python -V
Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)
```

When I launch Jupyter notebook from my home directory I have the options of a Python3 or a Python2 kernel, but when I CD to the directory I run my training from (and any other directory) I only have Python2 option.

I am getting very confused by this - I have uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda several times.

I have looked at this
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1280

Comment: related solution: [How do I add python3 kernel to jupyter IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28840041/3788772)

Comment: also this: [Kernels for Python 2 and 3](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-python-2-and-3)